# darktable 1.6 in PC-BSD

Tags: freebsd, pc-bsd

Is [darktable](http://www.darktable.org/install/#freebsd) 1.6 in PC-BSD repositories available or when will it be? Or is it possible to install it from freebsd?

Answer (score 0):

You can install package for FreeBSD, it should work. [link](http://www.darktable.org/install/#freebsd)

Answer (score 0):

## PC-BSD

darktable 1.6.9 is present in both of the following repository directories:

- http://pkg.cdn.pcbsd.org/10.0-RELEASE/amd64/All/
- http://pkg.cdn.pcbsd.org/11.0-CURRENTFEB2016/edge/amd64/All/

Output from the following command will include the URL for your preferred branch:

```
cat /usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/pcbsd.conf | grep -i url
```

## FreeBSD

http://www.freshports.org/graphics/darktable/ shows version 2.0.1 available as both a port and a package.